# Returning datetime from c# returns only date

Tags: c#, .net

I am returning **CalculationDate** of DateTime type from my WebApi controller method.

```
return response = new GetResponse
                       {
                           CalculationDate = DateTime.Parse(
                               "2016-07-19T21:18:47.473Z",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),                               
                       };
```

when I test it from fiddler I receive the response as below

```
{
  "success": true,
  "content": {
    "calculationDate": "2016-07-19", // without time and milliseconds part.       
  }
}
```

how should I return datetime so that I will receive both date and time along with milliseconds?

Comment: What is CalculationDate

Comment: Try to use the following:   CalculationDate = DateTime.Parse(
"2016-07-19T21:18:47.473Z".ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff",
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))

Comment: @Neil - it is of DateTime type

Comment: @DieterB - It works, If I change the datatype of CalculationDate  to string, but I can not change its datatype.

Comment: ok well if you try `DateTime dateset = DateTime.Parse("2016-07-19T21:18:47.473Z");` it would obviously work so there must be something wrong with `CalculationDate` maybe add its Structure so we can see

Comment: @Neil  - here is the model. public class GetResponse
    {
              public DateTime CalculationDate { get; set; }
    }

Comment: try with postman see if you get the same result

Comment: Why `CalculationDate` is `"calculationDate"` in the json? Which fiddler you use? Maybe it uses custom (simplified?) json serializer. Try to prepare [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see if problem is reproduce-able and you haven't make mistakes in your thoughts.

Comment: Which Json serializer are you using?

Comment: @Neil - same response with Postman.

Comment: @RubenAguilar - not using any serializer.

Comment: @Nareshsadu - You are using WebApi right? And in the fiddler data that you are showing I can see JSON. So your WebApi is serializing your object to JSON. If you don't change it you are using **JsonMediaTypeFormatter**.

Comment: @RubenAguilar - Thanks for the pointer. DateFormatString was set to "yyyy-MM-dd" on GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter. when I changes it.. it worked.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following setting in my Global.asax was the issue.

```
 var jsonFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
   jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

I had to change it to following

```
var jsonFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ";
```

@RubenAguilar - Thanks for the pointer